# Extend BigDecimal number

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have this program :

```
int r = 4;//number add to d
int n = 3;//number of 0 add after 25
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0025);
```

finaly i want to generate number : `0.0025004` and this number is generated by:
add `n` position after `d` then my number was : `0.0025000` and finaly add `0.000004` to my number 4 is `r`.

I know there are a several ways to do, but i want to `avoid loop`  and use a maximum fonctinnality of `BigDecimal`

Comment: What have u tried? have u looked at the BigDecimal interface API? Check out BigDecimal.scaleByPowerOfTen() and you can adapt it to what you want.

Comment: Also, accept some answers to your question - if you don't know what this means - read the FAQ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
int r = 4;// number add to d
int n = 3;// number of 0 add after 25
BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0025);
double f  = r / Math.pow(10, d.scale() + n);
System.out.println(d.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(f)));
```

I hope this is useful